# pythonic way to sample a point from a hyperplane of an euclidean space.

Tags: sampling, python

Consider the 8-dimensional euclidean space $\mathbb R^8$. I denote a point in $\mathbb R^8$ by

$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$$

I want to sample a point from a convex subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^8$, where $S$ is defined by five equations and one inequality (it is indeed convex)

$$
\begin{cases}
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4&=0.9\\
b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4&=0.9\\
a_1+a_2-b_1-b_2&=0\\
a_3-b_3&=0\\
a_4-b_4&=0\\
a_1-b_1&\ge0
\end{cases}
$$

($0\le a_i, b_i\le 1$)

I want to sample a point from $S$ randomly, I mean,like from uniform distribution.
Is there any way to achieve this using python?

**Note 1)**
One way to find such a point is to use linear programing(`scipy.optimize.linprog`).
That is, make an arbitrary set of coefficients $w_i$'s (which is easy in python) to make an arbitrary (linear) objective function :
$$f(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4) = w_1a_1+w_2a_2+w_3a_3+w_4a_4+w_5b_1+w_6b_2+w_7b_3+w_8b_4$$
Then, use linear programming to find the point $x_0$ where the objective function attains its minimum.
Since, the optima of linear programing problem happens on the boundary of the domain, we found a point $x_0$ in $S$.
But such an $x_0$ is on the boundary, not in the interior of the domain.
And I think it is not a good ways to get rich set of arbitrary points in $S$.

(After finding such boundary points, I can make a convex combination of them, to make an interior point of $S$. (Convexity of $S$ can be used here). But I think there are more general way to sample a point.)

**Note2)** The equations are too simple.
For example, the fourth and fifth equation is just $a_3=b_3$ and $a_4=b_4$.
But the equations can be more general (still linear).
So instead of substituting $b_3$ by $a_3$ and $b_4$ by $a_4$ or so to reduce the problem to that of deciding three independent variables, I want to literally sample from the set $S$.

Comment: Is $S$ bounded?

Comment: @BenjaminWang No.

Comment: Then how can there be a uniform distribution on $S$?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Oh no. It's bounded sorry.
Each $a_i$ and $b_i$ should be in between 0 and 1.

Comment: You could write the system of equations as the nullspace of a matrix $A$. Then find a basis of the nullspace of $A$. Orthogonalize this basis. Then sample uniformly coefficients and multiply to that basis. And only take the results where the inqeuality holds, too.

Comment: @Alex Writing the system as a matrix form $Ax=b$, the right hand side $b$ is not the zero vector. So the solution to the system is not the nullspace of $A$. Isn't it?

Comment: True, but take any solution $x_0$ of $Ax=b$. Then $A^{-1}(b) = x_0 + A^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @Alex Sorry for my late answer. By "orthogonalization", do you mean the SVD? I don't know how to orthogonalize non-square matrices. Wikipedia document for "orthogonalization" has no word "rectangular". Or should I pad zeros to make $A$ a square matrix?

Comment: @Alex Sorry for stupid comments. I think I understand your answer throughly, maybe. By orthogonalization of basis, you may mean the Gram-Schimidt method. And orthogonal (or orthonormal) basis can be use to pick a sample uniformly from the nullspace.

But, to the very problem that I've confronted, I found another way. So I stopped implementing it. I think `numpy` (like `np.nullspace`?) offers the right tool to do what I wanted to do. Thanks anyway.